# Change focus control when press enter key

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows form, i need when user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> set focus to next control.
Any idea how to achive this
(without using Key Press events)

Comment: Without the KeyPress event you can't know that the user pressed the Enter key

Comment: what about ProcessCmdKey event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can catch the KeyPreview of your form.  Set KeyPreview to true in the constructor and then you can use this:

```
protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0100 && (int)m.WParam == 13)
    {
        this.ProcessTabKey(true);
    }
    return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ProcessCmdKey checking if keyData contains the <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key then using the [`SelectNextControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method to set your focus.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData.HasFlag(Keys.Enter)) 
    {
        SelectNextControl(ActiveControl,true,true,true,true);
        return true; //Stops the beeping
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use key press events you will have to override `ProcessCmdKey`

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Return)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed the Enter key");
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: to focus next control i have to use SendKeys.Send("{Tab}")